# Break up a txt file with breaks into multiple data frames in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, txt

I have a txt file in a format similar to this:

Title

Sub Heading: A

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD

1       2       3       4

5       6       7       8
```

Sub Heading: B

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD

1       2       3       4

5       6       7       8
```

Sub Heading: C

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD

1       2       3       4

5       6       7       8
```

The aim is to read the txt file in pandas, and create a dictionary of dataframes with the sub heading as each key for the dataframe which follows it.

df[A]:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD

1       2       3       4

5       6       7       8
```

So far I have read the file as follows:

```
with open('filename.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
```

But can't get my read round how to break it up for each sub-heading.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Are there always 4 columns or could be more?

Comment: There is always the same number of columns after each sub-heading

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use *regex* with [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) :

```
import re
from io import StringIO
​
with open("file.txt") as f:
    dfs = { # or pd.read_csv with `delim_whitespace=True`
        m.group(1): pd.read_table(StringIO(m.group(2).strip()))
        for m in re.finditer(r".+?:\s*(\w+)\s*(.*?)(?=[\w ]+:|\Z)",
                             f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)
    }
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/DoJI9E/1)]

Output :

```
>>> print(dfs)

{'A':    ColA  ColB  ColC   ColD
 0     1     2      3     4
 1     5     6      7     8,
 'B':    ColA  ColB  ColC   ColD
 0     1     2      3     4
 1     5     6      7     8,
 'C':    ColA  ColB  ColC   ColD
 0     1     2      3     4
 1     5     6      7     8}
```

Comment: Thanks - will try this and look through regex, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the beginning:

Let's create three random dataframe:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1, 3], 'ColB': [2, 4], 'ColC': [3, 7], 'ColD': [4, 10]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1, 4], 'ColB': [2, 5], 'ColC': [3, 8], 'ColD': [4, 11]})
df_C = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1, 2], 'ColB': [2, 6], 'ColC': [3, 9], 'ColD': [4, 12]})
```

Then create a new df_dictionary to store all the dataframe:

`df = {'A': df_A, 'B': df_B, 'C': df_C}`

In this way you can call the df['A'] to check each subheading~

Then let's deal with the file

You have already deal with the reading files The logic is just read each line, store the line in a value until it met the next sub heading~

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_dict = {}
subheading = 0
value = []

with open('my_file.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('Sub Heading: '):
            if len(value)!=0:
              df_dict[subheading] = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(value)), delim_whitespace=True)
            value = [] #clear the cache
            subheading = line.split(': ')[1]
            continue # avoid all subheadings store in the value
        value.append(line)
#Remeber to join the last subheadings.
if len(value)!=0 :
    df_dict[subheading] = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(value)), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I know this way is a little slow, but it may good for beginner.

Comment: By the way, I don't clear understand why use a variable to do the index of the dictionary, you can by assigan A = 'A'.....but it is strange.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful - I managed to get a solution that worked from this